# Method for minimizing relays in a switching/steering network - combinatorics algorithm?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, relay, network, topology

I'm developing an industrial power device which has multiple power supplies that need to be multiplexed to multiple outputs (MIMO) through a network of relays. Similar to how digital logic can be reduced to a minimum set of gates, I want to reduce my relay network to a minimum number of relays.

**GENERAL SETUP:**

**Inputs:**

Three generators: A, B, C. Generators A and B can output one of two modes at a time, like GenA_High OR GenA_Low, for example. Generator C only has LOW mode. Here's the list of the three generators, and any combination of these can be operating at the same time.

1. Either GenA_HIGH or GenA_LOW
2. Either GenB_HIGH or GenB_LOW
3. GenC_LOW

**Outputs:**

The outputs are such that there are two output ports: P0, P1. In each port there are three outputs: HIGH, LOW1, and LOW2. Here's the output:

1. P0_HIGH
2. P0_LOW1
3. P0_LOW2
4. P1_HIGH
5. P1_LOW1
6. P1_LOW2

There are a few additional limitations for the system:

- The HIGH inputs can only be output on the HIGH outputs, and the LOW inputs can only be output on the LOW outputs.
- Each input can only be present on ONE output at a time - it's not allowed to have, for example, GenA_HIGH be present on both P0_HIGH and P1_HIGH.
- Any other permutation is allowed, and is only limited by the fact that there can only be up to three active inputs at any time.

**QUESTION:**

How can I be confident the design has the minimum number of relays? What's the simplest and cheapest relay topology (SPST, SPDT, DPDT, etc.) that can be used so as to reduce size and cost?

We have an even more complex version of this being planned, so it would be good to pin down a scalable, general solution to this problem.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to structure this problem as a traditional digital logic problem, but have run into all kinds of problems. Despite this seeming like "logic", it's not... but it's very close. I've also been trying to massage this into a known combinatorics problem, like a knapsack/packing problem or a route-finding problem, but that is not my specialty.

I'm hoping someone out there has seen this kind of thing before and can offer some direction!

EDIT: I've been looking into Constraint Satisfaction Problems, and those types of problems seem very close to what I need here. I'm still trying to learn more about it. I'd love to know if this is a red herring or if there is some better-fitting (and simpler!) algorithm?

Comment: There are other considerations than just the number of relays--you need to consider what kinds of voltages and currents you need to switch, how frequently switching happens, how long you want this setup to last before needing to replace a relay...

Comment: Yes, of course! I will definitely size the relays appropriately upon minimizing the network. I purposely neglected the specifications like switching, currents, and voltages because the minimization problem is the thing I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: The reason I bring it up is that those specifications will determine what kinds of relays you have access to--for instance, if you're looking at switching kilovolts, you won't find anything but SPST reed relays unless you want to pay hundreds of dollars for a kilovac. (this is a problem I've run into several times recently)

Comment: Ah, got it. That makes sense. My application voltage isn't that high, so thankfully there are quite a few options available!

Comment: Also, you neglected to mention (or I overlooked it): do the inputs need to be able to be totally disconnected from any output? Or is it fine to leave them connected when the input and output are both not being used?

Comment: It's OK to leave them connected, because the inputs (power supplies) are just turned off. But that's a bit beside the point. If I had a method for solving a problem like this generally, I could conceivably add or modify rules like that if the design changed.

Comment: what controls the generator output level?

Comment: I don't think there's a *theorem* that ensures that, since it seems like the historicaly problem of NAND synthesis. Shannon thesis probably could help since he treated relay logic networks

Comment: _"I want to reduce my relay network to a minimum number of relays."_ - Why?

Comment: I think everyone is missing the point a little bit. The details of how exactly this gets built and functions electrically are irrelevant, though I can assure everyone that the functionality of the design is sound. I'm only trying to minimize the relay network here. Maybe this question would have been better suited for a CompSci board?

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoMarcantonio. I'll look into some of the methods of NAND synthesis and Shannon's thesis! Helpful!

Comment: @BruceAbbott ""I want to reduce my relay network to a minimum number of relays." why? << relays are not cheap and also there is a non trivial commutation time involved